# leave special character as is in sql xml path('')

Tags: sql, xml

I have a query

```
select name, address, description from table1 for xml path('co'), type
```

but when there's special character in any column, it gets replaced with HTML code. How do i get it to leave that as is and not converting it to html code? Please advise. Thank you so much

Comment: It is converted to XML. What else do you expect?

Comment: I would like for it to stay as & instead &amp